# How do I install TREE when the command line doesn't work?

Tags: apt, tree

I tried to install TREE via the sudo apt-get install tree command but nothing but an error happens ("sudo: apt-get: command not found"). How do I fix this?

Comment: Could you post what errors `apt-get` writes?

Comment: Whick kind of error? It could be about permissions, dependencies, etc.

Comment: @jcbermu sudo: apt-get: command not found

Comment: What is your distribution? May be it use another package manager...

Comment: @purplepsycho I am very new to Linux and therefore do not have a clue about what you asked

Comment: What is your system name? Ubuntu, Red Hat, Centos, Fedora... ?

Comment: I think it's only a custom built one for learners cause it doesn't say. Idk

Comment: Try this command to find out the distro:
cat /etc/*-release

Comment: That doesn't work

Comment: If its custom build linux system, it may not even have a package management system, you may have to build all software from sources. You can find sources for tree from here http://mama.indstate.edu/users/ice/tree/ .

Comment: Then let's hope a compiler is installed :). Or check if at least wget or curl is installed, so you can download the binaries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Distribution

A system built on Linux is called a "distribution".

Distribution examples:

- Ubuntu
- Debian
- Fedora
- Arch
- OpenSuse
- ...

To install a software on a distribution, you have several possibilities:

- Build the software from source,
- Install the program with a "package manager".

### Package manager

Almost each distribution use one package manager, most known are:

- apt-get (debian, ubuntu)
- pacman (arch)
- yum (fedora)
- ...

Each package manager has its syntax, type `man <package manager>`.

### Build from source

It will depends on the software you want to install, but in most cases:

- get the sources:

  - go to software web page
  - download the source (.tar.gz, .tgz, .zip... file)
  - uncompress it
- build it:

  ```
  # in software source directory
  ./configure
  make
  make install
  ```

Comment: Okay, so I presume that I download the source because everything else doesn't work?

Comment: I think so. Downloald the tgz file from tree site (StefanR gives you the link), unzip it, and try to build it.

Comment: I also often install things from source on Debian, even althought that distro has a very nice pacakge management. I do it because when I install from source I get newer versions and features.